# A ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

For a nontrivial homomorphism from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$, I know it’s invective and maps $1$ to $1$ and i to +i or -i. Then is such a map onto? I can’t go further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you believe Zorn's lemma, there are lots of field maps from $\Bbb C$
to itself, not all surjective. Take a transcendence basis $A$ of $\Bbb C$
over $\Bbb Q$. Then $A$ has cardinality $|\Bbb C|$. Take an injection $\phi:A\to A$. Then, $\phi$ extends to a field map $\Phi$ from $\Bbb C$ to itself (this requires
Zorn, as does the existence of $A$). If $\phi$ is not surjective, neither is $\Phi$.

Comment: Is there a result of Hom($\mathbb{C}$,$\mathbb{C}$)$?